# Is there an event when a SearchView is focused?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, searchview

I'm using a `SearchView` to enter a number from a bluetooth barcode reader.

The `SearchView` is focused as follows:

```
svActListaPedidosFragmento.setFocusable(true);
svActListaPedidosFragmento.setIconified(false);
```

The search is done as follows:

```
  private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener svActListaPedidosFragmentoOnQueryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //my code
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

The problem is that when the `SearchView` is focused, the software keyboard appears. Currently I know how to hide this keyboard, but I need an event that tells me that the `SearchView` has been focused.

I have read several examples, but none works.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `OnClickListener` to `SearchView`